# How to install Jenkins on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

How do I install jenkins on Windows 10 Home?
I am going through this link to install jenkins on local system.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/
anytime I try to login after installation, I get following error:

[image: Jenkins]

From the Jenkins website I get following solution:
Logon to the computer with administrative privileges.

Open the Administrative Tools and open the Local Security Policy

Expand Local Policy and click on User Rights Assignment

In the right pane, right-click Log on as a service and select properties.

Click on the Add User or Group… button to add the new user.

In the Select Users or Groups dialogue, find the user you wish to enter and click OK

Click OK in the Log on as a service Properties to save changes.

**But this is not helpful as I am trying to do this on Win 10 Home hence local security policy is not available.**
I tried to check system requirements also from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/windows/ but **could not get definitive answer.**
Are there any workarounds or solution for this?

Comment: Read [Installing Jenkins - Windows](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/) ... "Keep in mind that to run Jenkins as a service, the account that runs Jenkins must have permission to login as a service"

Comment: Follow this link youtube.com/watch?v=0s4FzAahtuY Download the zip file, extract, run the batch file as administrator. Wait for the installation finishes. Relogin again.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and could not find a solution. I ended up installing docker desktop on my Win10 Home and now run the precompiled image. Works perfectly.

Comment: Follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0s4FzAahtuY

Download the zip file, extract, run the batch file as administrator. Wait for the installation finishes. Relogin again.