# How to install Jenkins on Windows Home

Tags: windows, jenkins, installation, server, account

When I try give my account to Jenkins for it being able to login the error pops out. I've researched it a bit and it seems that the problem is that I have Windows Home. Is there any way to run it on my os?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Jenkins on Windows 10 Home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230916/how-to-install-jenkins-on-windows-10-home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run Jenkins using Docker since Docker uses WSL.
Download installation file named `Docker` by this link:

```
https://www.jenkins.io/download/
```

Then run our container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name my_jenkins jenkins/jenkins
```

After running the container in your browser go to:

```
localhost:8080
```

Then to unlock Jenkins use this command and enter into Jenkins output that looks something like this `d7383b6a8d7149cc87d481c7ddb9412d`:

```
docker exec my_jenkins cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

After that configurating steps are fairly easy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).